# How to describe a doctor who is short?

Tags: creative-writing, characters

How to describe a character who is a doctor but short in height without saying he's short?

The character is a doctor who's under 5 feet, and I want the reader to know this without mentioning he is short.

Comment: Could you be more specific? Why not mention he is short? Does it matter that they are a doctor? What is the context? And exactly how short do you mean?

Comment: I mean, vertically challenged is the PC version.

Comment: The Character is a doctor who's under 5 feet, and I want the reader to know this without mention he is short.   A little context...."The examination table faced the doorway, and I was sitting on its edge. My eyes scanned the room in desperation, landing on the two framed medical degrees decorating the wall. A hand touched my shoulder. “Mrs. Brown, Mrs. Brown can you hear me?”  My eyes shifted back to the voice that had called out my mother-in-law’s name. Dr. Drabrick stood to the right of me waiting for a response, eyes tired and heavy with the look of sadness on his face."

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few things I would say :

adjectives :
- stubby (implying he is fat, don't know if you want that)

### - low (old english)

imagery :
- "he had trouble measuring me, and had to stand on a stool"
- " he look up to me  to meet my eyeline as I shook his hand"
- "he stood up straight to gain a few centimetres

i'll edit this answer if other forms come to me

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Please let me know if you come up with any addition ways to describe this short character.